# Ceiling fan running slow and making noises, or not running at all

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

****New update new pictures!****
Ok I took the voltage meter to both of my capacitors and got no voltage from either. However in the photos they are in tact and have not blown. Before I end up buying a whole new ceiling fan, I would like to save a bit of money and buy replacement capacitors
The only problem is I have searched for hours trying to find an exact duplicate capacitor and couldn't find anything close. Can I order a different capacitor and what would I need to look for in order to supply the correct voltage?

I have a ceiling fan in my master bedroom that I have been having a problem with that I cannot diagnose. As of late, every time I flip the switch to turn it on, it starts spinning really really really slow, and then  after a while I will hear some sort of click or knock noise and then the fan starts spinning normally. However, after 20 minutes or so, I hear that same same click or knock noise and it slows down extremely slow. 
It's now at the point that, when I turn it on, it won't do anything!
I'm not sure how old this fan is and I don't want to get a new one especially if this is just a cheap part fix.
Any ideas?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ISUS.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhJPn.jpg)

Comment: Can you get your hands on a meter or amp-clamp?

Comment: Check the capacitor. If it's bulged or leaking, it's obviously dead. If it looks good, you'll have to test it with a meter.

Comment: It sounds like it is just getting old and the grease is getting thick or a bearing has gone bad.  I have a floor fan like that and have used WD-40 on it but it is clear to me that I am going to have to just replace it.  If it is large enough to have a starting capacitor, then certainly follow the advice given by @Tester101

Comment: See photos of capacitors but can't find exact duplicates. What other capacitor could I buy to supply the correct voltage?